# Submitting NULL to database - single quotes issue?

Tags: php, mysql

I wish to UPDATE NULL into my database if the post value is blank. If it's not blank, i want it to insert the value posted.

```
if(empty($post['gallery']))$post['gallery'] = NULL;
```

It's a rather large query so here is the bit i'm interested in:

```
"article.article_gallery_id = '".$post['gallery']."', ".
```

The above never inserts a NULL but a 0.

This does insert a NULL:

```
"article.article_gallery_id = NULL, ".
```

I believe the problem lays with the single quotes around the $post['gallery']. If I remove them, the query does not work at all.

How can I fix this?

I don;t want to use PDO and don't worry about security - I've taken bits out for the example.

Comment: Don't use the old mysql_ functions, since they're being deprecated. With something like that, you're much better off use PDO or mysqli.

Comment: I think you meant `$_POST` instead of `$post`. If so, you're vulnerable to SQL injection. Please switch to [prepared statements](http://bobby-tables.com/php.html).

Comment: What datatype is your `article_gallery_id` column?

Comment: This should be handled as a part of a larger change to validate and sanitize your input data. As-is, you are inserting (mostly) unfiltered user input directly into your database, which can compromise your security and/or data integrity.

Comment: @George Cummins I know, I have taken all this out for an easy example

Comment: -1 for *"I don't worry about security"*; also what's wrong with PDO?

Comment: Yes,  `NULL` is not the same as `'NULL'`. This is basic SQL.

Answer (score 1):

PHP `null` will not convert to SQL's `NULL` when putting it into a string.
If the value if empty, the query needs to look like `article.article_gallery_id = NULL`.
If it's not empty, the query needs to look like `article.article_gallery_id = 'value'`.
Compare the use of quotes and no quotes and the `NULL` keyword. You'll need to explicitly format the query this way, you can't rely on a PHP `null` value.

Comment: The OP is inserting the single quotes no matter what, which means they'll never get a SQL `NULL`.

Comment: @NullUserException Exactly, which is why I'm pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to put quotes in the SQL around null:

```
if(empty($post['gallery'])){ $post['gallery'] = "NULL"; } 
$sql = "UPDATE article SET article.article_gallery_id = " . $post['gallery'] . " WHERE somefield = 'someValue'";
```

You should avoid using MySQL functionality as its depreciated. Try [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) or [PDO](http://php.net/PDO)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, remove quotes, because you are dealing with integers, not strings.

Why does it fail then? Try this:

```
echo "column = " . null;
```

It echoes "column = ", because `null` is what it says: nothing. You need to account for the special case when `$post['gallery']` is null.

```
 $sqlQuery .=
     "article.article_gallery_id = "
     . (is_null($post['gallery']) ? 'NULL' : $post['gallery'])
     . " [rest of your query here] ";
```

Answer (score 0):

To insert `null` into a database you have to remove the quotes around it. I noticed you said you tried it and it didn't work. I imagine what happened then is that you had a different error occur. You said the query is long so maybe the error happened somewhere else?  Here's a simple way to solve it:

```
$post['gallery'] = (!empty($post['gallery'])) "'$post[gallery]'" : 'NULL';

"article.article_gallery_id = $post[gallery], ".
```

If you notice I removed the single quotes from the query and I add them to the post var if it's not empty.

I hope that helps!

Answer (score -1):

You should set your table default to null, but to actually fix this you'll have to switch your quotes around, pHP evaluates any var between " and not so now it set an empty value and not literally null.

THe best solution is this though

```
if(empty($post['gallery']))$post['gallery'] = "NULL";
```

then it actually puts in the NULL value mysql needs

Comment: Nope, this still puts a 0.

Comment: that's because you're column doesn't allow for NULL then, it's not the code that's the problem, its the DB. '0' appears because your column is setup as an INT and doesn't allow NULL!